# find users with overlapping subscription dates

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

I have a subscription table:

```
user_id | start_date | end_date
1         1/1/2019   1/31/2019
2         1/15/2019  1/17/2019
3         1/29/2019  2/4/2019
4         2/5/2019   2/10/2019
```

I am looking to get the list of users with overlapping subscription with ANY of the other users.

```
user_id overlap
1   True
2   True
3   True
4   False
```

I tried this :

```
select  u1.user_id,
        case when u1.end_date > u2.start_date and u1.start_Date < u2.end_date 
        then 'True' 
        else 'False' end as overlap
from subscriptions u1 
join subscriptions u2 
    on u1.user_id <> u2.user_id
```

but it gives me following results:

```
1   True
1   True
1   False
2   True
2   False
2   False
3   True
3   False
3   False
4   False
4   False
4   False
```

Comment: Hi, I don't use PostgreSQL that much, but do you have the `overlap` function on yours?  It is something like: `(start1, end1) OVERLAPS (start2, end2)` according to the docs. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-datetime.html

Comment: I am not supposed to use the in-built functions for this query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am thinking that you can use `exists`:

```
select s.*,
       (exists (select 1
                from subscriptions s2
                where s2.start_date < s.end_date and
                      s2.end_date > s.start_date and
                      s2.user_id <> s.user_id
               )
       ) as has_overlap_flag
from subscriptions s;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0a00aea197ce1c83c8883a981690f4af) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: how can I handle records with end_date as null (indicating end date to be in future) without using UNION @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @gabs . . . You can use `coalesce()` with the current or future date.